# How to access to the real android namespace?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a project that is MyProject.Cient.Android because it is a client for android devices. I would to use this name beacause I have another project that is MyProject.Client.Wpf, so in this way I can know the kinf of project.

The problem is that when I create my blank android project, I get this method:

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
```

Then problem is that I can use Android.Content.PM.Permission[] because it is searching in Myproject.Client.Android instead of the real Android.Contect namespace.

So I would like to know how is the way to force this method to search in Android.Content instead of MyProject.Client.Android.

Thanks.

Comment: `global::Android.Content.PM.Permission` but I would sugest to change your namespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll save yourself a lot of headache if your rename your Android project to "MyProject.Client.Droid".

But in the interim, you can use `global::Android` to get to the default Android namespace.